# Sending arabic characters in URL

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, query-string, urlencode

i have these arabic sentence:

> نايتيد أمامه عشرة أيام فقط لكي يقرر مستقبل برباتوف في النادي

It must be sent in the url. I tried this approach:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/?q='.urlencode('نايتيد أمامه عشرة أيام فقط لكي يقرر مستقبل برباتوف في النادي');
```

The result of that encoding is:
    %D9%86%D8%A7%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%8A%D8%AF+%D8%A3%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%87+%D8%B9%D8%B4%D8%B1%D8%A9+%D8%A3%D9%8A%D8%A7%D9%85+%D9%81%D9%82%D8%B7+%D9%84%D9%83%D9%8A+%D9%8A%D9%82%D8%B1%D8%B1+%D9%85%D8%B3%D8%AA%D9%82%D8%A8%D9%84+%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%AA%D9%88%D9%81+%D9%81%D9%8A+%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%AF%D9%8A

But the php script is receiving this in the $_GET['q'] querystring:

```
Ù†Ø§ÙŠØªÙŠØ¯ Ø£Ù…Ø§Ù…Ù‡ Ø¹Ø´Ø±Ø© Ø£ÙŠØ§Ù… ÙÙ‚Ø· Ù„ÙƒÙŠ ÙŠÙ‚Ø±Ø± Ù…Ø³ØªÙ‚Ø¨Ù„ Ø¨Ø±Ø¨Ø§ØªÙˆÙ ÙÙŠ Ø§Ù„Ù†Ø§Ø¯ÙŠ
```

The php file is UTF-8 encoded. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the proper way to URL encode Unicode characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912811/what-is-the-proper-way-to-url-encode-unicode-characters)

Comment: How are you outputting the value of `$_GET['q']`?

Comment: did you try: utf8_decode($_GET['q']);

Comment: To a web browser? Is the browser set to display the page as utf-8? (The output you're showing is treating your bytes as Windows-1252)

Comment: If the file is encoded in UTF-8 then the encoding part is done correctly. However, you need to convert the encoding of the incoming string to UTF-8 when you *read* the parameter. Use `iconv` or `mb_convert_encoding` for this. Also, `rawurlencode` should be used "by default" instead of `urlencode` unless there is specific reason not to do it.

Comment: @Sudhir: That won't work because arabic characters do not exist in ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Did you tried `file_put_contents('test', $_GET['q'])` and open it in editor with utf8 enabled to check if it's really not utf8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must urldecode your encoded entities. Furthermore remember that UTF8 and PHP are not a great combination.

Comment: Huh? PHP and UTF8 are not a great combination? Why do you say so?

Answer (score 3):

As I mention in other question, You should do urlencode the Arabic text

```
urlencode('كلام-عربي')
```

And its very important to add the charset code to the head tag of the page, otherwise the link will not work

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Answer (score 1):

dont use urlencode just use rawurlencode

Answer (score 0):

As I mention in other question, You should do `urldecode` the Arabic text in URI

```
echo urldecode(explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 2));
```