# Is it standard to UTF8 + escape our international URLs?

Tags: http, url, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I see that many sites (amazon, wikipedia, others) use UTF8-encoded, URL-escaped unicode in their URLs, and those URLs are prettified by (at least) Chrome.

For example, we would represent http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/メインページ as http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%9A%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8 when writing our http headers, and Chrome and Firefox seem to understand this in a graceful way. (I didn't test on IE.)

Is there a governing standard for this behavior? Or is it strictly a de facto standard? Or is it completely non-standard?

I'd really like to see a link to the defining paragraph of some RFC.

Comment: In _what_ standards? Please use links in your question.

Comment: Seriously though, without knowing _what_ standards you mean, how can anyone answer this?

Comment: What is an international URL?

Comment: Possible duplicates: [*What is the proper way to URL encode Unicode characters?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/912811/53114), [*Unicode characters in URLs*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2742852/53114)

Comment: @bukzor So you mean URLs with non-ASCII characters, right?

Comment: @Gumbo: Those are similar, and helpful, but not duplicate (imo). They discuss *how* to do unicode URLs, but not *why*.

Comment: @Oded: This question is looking for a standard. It's part of the answer, not part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

The [URI standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-16) says:

> When a new URI scheme defines a component that represents textual data
> consisting of characters from the Universal Character Set [[UCS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#ref-UCS)], the
> data should first be encoded as octets according to the UTF-8
> character encoding [[STD63](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#ref-STD63)]; then only those octets that do not
> correspond to characters in the unreserved set should be percent-
> encoded.

That seems pretty definitive.

I'm still unsure about when it was ratified, or the current browser support.

Comment: And other standards depend on this.  JavaScript's definition of [`encodeURI`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.1.3.3) and its dual `decodeURI` are defined thus: "each instance of certain characters is replaced by one, two or three escape sequences representing the UTF-8 encoding of the character."

Comment: The only problem is it says: “When a *new* URI scheme […]”

Answer (score 0):

[RFC 3987](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3987) is the new standard for handling International URI/URLs, known as IRIs.  The old standard, [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), does not support Unicode.  Anyone not using IRIs yet has to come up with their own way of encoding unsupported characters for their own needs.  Percent-encoding UTF-8 octets is one way, but it is certainly not the only way that is actually in use.