# Have Spring tell FreeMarker the URL encoding to use

Tags: url, spring-mvc, freemarker

I am using FreeMarker with Spring to generate my HTML pages. In my Freemarker page I try to URL escape a `String` value, like this:

```
        <a href="<@spring.url "/ext/Thing/${thing?url}/"/>">Thing ${thing}</a>
```

This results in an exception from FreeMarker that complains

> ERROR 2014-02-03 11:08:45,513 Error executing FreeMarker template
>   FreeMarker template error:
>   To do URL encoding, the framework that encloses FreeMarker must specify the output encoding or the URL encoding charset, so ask the programmers to fix it. Or, as a last chance, you can set the url_encoding_charset setting in the template, e.g. <#setting url_escaping_charset='ISO-8859-1'>, or give the charset explicitly to the buit-in, e.g. foo?url('ISO-8859-1').

What to do to fix this problem?

Comment: I am answering my own question, [as is encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 4):

First, [what "URL encoding charset" to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912811/what-is-the-proper-way-to-url-encode-unicode-characters)? That [should be UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/913653/545127).

In this context, "the framework that encloses FreeMarker" is Spring, and specifically the [`org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/freemarker/FreeMarkerConfigurer.html) bean that must be present to use FreeMarker with Spring. You have to provide a `freemarkerSettings` `Property` (key-value mapping) that has a value for the [`url_escaping_charset`](http://freemarker.org/docs/api/freemarker/core/Configurable.html#setURLEscapingCharset%28java.lang.String%29) property. In the Spring web servlet configuration file (beans configuration file) write something like this:

```
 <bean id="freemarkerConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
    <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="freemarkerSettings">
        <props>
            <prop key="url_escaping_charset">UTF-8</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
 </bean>
```

Comment: can you add the java version : `freemarkerConfigurer.getConfiguration().setURLEscapingCharset("UTF-8")`