# URLencode Japanese characters

Tags: python

How would I urlencode the following? What I am currently doing throws a `KeyError`.

```
episode_title = 'ザ・ロック（日本語吹替版)'
try:
    qs = urllib.quote(episode_title)
except:
    qs = urllib.quote(episode_title.encode('utf8'))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  KeyError: u'\u30b6'
```

Comment: what python version are you on?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912811/what-is-the-proper-way-to-url-encode-unicode-characters -- TL;DR: unconditionally urllib.urlencode the utf-8 encoding of your Unicode string.

Comment: If you are doing this using Python2, doing `episode_title = u'ザ・ロック（日本語吹替版)'` works with the encoded result of that `episode_title` unicode string (i.e. the statement in the exception block).

Comment: try adding unicode to the string: `episode_title = u'ザ・ロック（日本語吹替版)'`, and do: `qs = urllib.quote(episode_title.encode('utf8'))` and see if this works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe add an `decode('utf-8')` to your string.

```
import urllib
episode_title = "ザ・ロック（日本語吹替版)".decode('utf-8')
try:
    qs = urllib.quote(episode_title)
except:
    qs = urllib.quote(episode_title.encode('utf8'))
print qs
```

## Result:

```
%E3%82%B6%E3%83%BB%E3%83%AD%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%EF%BC%88%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E5%90%B9%E6%9B%BF%E7%89%88%29
```

*PS: I use **iPython**, and your code works fine.* Maybe you can switch to another Editor.