# How to decode a url with accents in C#

Tags: c#, unicode, urldecode

I've been trying to decode %E9(é).

```
WebUtility.HtmlDecode("%E9")
```

doesn't work.
It puts a ? sign instead of a é.

Comment: When I use `WebUtility.HtmlEncode("é")`, I get: `&#233;`, not `%E9`. When I run `HtmlDecode("&#233;");`, I get `é`. So I think `HtmlDecode` is not the method you're looking for.

Comment: @user3208848, Try  `WebUtility.UrlDecode("%C3%A9");`

Comment: The correct answer to this question is very dependent on where that url with accents is coming from. According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912811/what-is-the-proper-way-to-url-encode-unicode-characters the standard on the web is UTF-8, so trying to decode `"%E9"` (which doesn't represent a valid UTF-8 string) is a bit dodgy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've tested this and found that `HttpUtility.UrlDecode("%E9")` returns question mark that You mentioned. It seems that it You have to manually specify appropriate encoding for this to work correctly with `%E9` encoded value.

You can try:

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode("%E9", System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.Default);
```

or

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode("%E9", System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.UTF7);
```

Both should return the character decoded as You expected.

Comment: UTF-7 is not used anywhere, it likely works in this case by coincidence.

Comment: It may be not popular, but this does not mean nobody uses it ;).

Answer (score 3):

For Url decode, you should use UrlDecode instead of HtmlDecode. Also, you need to specify the encoding for this to work because the encoded value `%E9` is not `UTF-8` value, and by default `UrlDecode` returns string decoded using `UTF-8`.

Addition to Lukasz's answer, you can also use:

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode("%E9", System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));
```

Comment: Perfect solution!