# Trouble understanding C# URL decode with Unicode character(s) in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, unicode, encoding

I'm currently working on something that requires me to pass a Base64 string to a PowerShell script. But while decoding the string back to the original I'm getting some unexpected results as I need to use UTF-7 during decoding and I don't understand why. Would someone know why?

The [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding) would suggest that it's insufficient to use Base64 if you have Unicode characters in your string. Thus you need to use a workaround that consists of using `encodeURIComponent` and a replace. I don't really get why the replace is needed and shortened it to `btoa(escape('✓ à la mode'))` to encode the string. The result of that operation would be `JXUyNzEzJTIwJUUwJTIwbGElMjBtb2Rl`.

Using PowerShell to decode the string back to the original, I need to first undo the Base64 encoding. In order to do `System.Convert` can be used (which results in a byte array) and its output can be converted to a UTF-8 string using `System.Text.Encoding`. Together this would look like the following:

```
$bytes = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($inputstring)
$utf8string = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($bytes)
```

What's left to do is URL decode the whole thing. As it is a UTF-8 string I'd expect only to need to run the URL decode without any further parameters. But if you do that you end up with a accented a that looks like `�` in a file or `?` on the console. To get the actual original string it's necessary to tell the URL decode to use UTF-7 as the character set. It's nice that this works but I don't really get why it's necessary since the string should be UTF-8 and UTF-8 certainly supports an accented a. See the last two lines of the entire script for what I mean. With those two lines you will end up with one line that has the garbled text and one which has the original text in the same file encoded as UTF-8

Entire PowerShell script:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
$inputstring = "JXUyNzEzJTIwJUUwJTIwbGElMjBtb2Rl"
$bytes = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($inputstring)
$utf8string = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($bytes)
[System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode($utf8string) | Out-File -Encoding utf8 C:\temp\output.txt
[System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode($utf8string, [System.Text.UnicodeEncoding]::UTF7) | Out-File -Append -Encoding utf8 C:\temp\output.txt
```

Clarification:
The problem isn't the conversion of the Base64 to UTF-8. The problem is some inconsistent behavior of the `UrlDecode` of C#. If you run `escape('✓ à la mode')` in your browser you will end up with the following string `%u2713%20%E0%20la%20mode`. So we have a Unicode representation of the check mark and a HTML entity for the `á`. If we use this directly in `UrlDecode` we end up with the same error. My current assumption would be that it's an issue with the encoding of the PowerShell window and pasting characters into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it actually isn't all that strange. It's just for what I want to do it's advantages to use a newer function. I'm still not sure why it works if you use the UTF-7 encoding. But anyways, as an explanation:

> ... The hexadecimal form for characters, whose code unit value is 0xFF or less, is a two-digit escape sequence: %xx. For characters with a greater code unit, the four-digit format %uxxxx is used.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape

As TesselatingHecksler pointed out [What is the proper way to URL encode Unicode characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/912811/478656) would indicate that the `%u` format wasn't formerly standardized. A newer version to escape characters exists though, which is [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

> The encodeURIComponent() function encodes a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) component by replacing each instance of certain characters by one, two, three, or four escape sequences representing the UTF-8 encoding of the character (will only be four escape sequences for characters composed of two "surrogate" characters).

The output of this function actually works with the C# implementation of `UrlDecode` without supplying an additional encoding of UTF-7.

The original linked Mozilla article about a Base64 encode for an UTF-8 strings modifies the whole process in a way to allows you to just call the Base64 decode function in order to get the whole string. This is realized by converting the URL encode version of the string to bytes.