# Acute accents in setAttribute in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've this weird problem with JavaScript when I create an image element and set the source attribute. The file name let's say is `"áéíóú.jpg"` and when I set it as `src` It get:

```
src = %C3%A1,%20%C3%A9,%20%C3%AD,%20%C3%B3,%20%C3%BA.jpg".
```

I set the attribute with:

```
img.src = src;
```

And in the debug session src is:

```
src = "á, é, í, ó, ú.jpg"
```

[IMAGE OF THE PROBLEM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FI3wh.png)

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.className+="materialboxed";
img.src = src;
img.setAttribute('width', '175');
img.setAttribute('height', '150');
```

Comment: The [`%` encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) is normal and how URLs support spaces and most of Unicode. – Related: [Unicode characters in URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742852/unicode-characters-in-urls) – Also, [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

Comment: What's the issue?  The spaces?

Comment: I get the conversion to UTF-8 and the %-sign notation, but I don't get where the commas and the spaces are coming from.

Comment: What exactly is meant by "when I set it as src"?  I don't see any issue [in my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pzs14L6s/1/)

Comment: I would expect the escaped sequence to be "%E1%E9%ED%F3%FA.jpg" - how did you generate it?

Comment: try to use https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski That would appear to be [ISO 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) (Latin 1). [That isn't common with percent-encoding.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912811/what-is-the-proper-way-to-url-encode-unicode-characters)

Comment: @JonathanLonowski doh, yes!  So therefore I expect the escaped sequence to be "%C3%A1%C3%A9%C3%AD%C3%B3%C3%BA.jpg"

Comment: @JonathanLonowski, yes, which is why it's confusing when it says "The file name let's say is "áéíóú.jpg" and when I set it as src It get:" - So I don't know if the question is "Why is it encoded?" or "Where did the commas and spaces come from?"

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski Ah. Missed that mention at the top.

Comment: If you're also questioning the spaces and commas... Does the `src` variable perhaps get its value, at least in part, from an Array? If the accented characters start out in one, `[ 'á', 'é', 'í', 'ó', 'ú' ]`, and you either convert that to or combine that with a string (such as `accents + '.jpg'`), the default behavior will be to `.join(', ')` the values, which would result in `'á, é, í, ó, ú'`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `decodeURIComponent()`

```
img.src = decodeURIComponent(src);
```

example:

```
decodeURIComponent('%C3%A1,%20%C3%A9,%20%C3%AD,%20%C3%B3,%20%C3%BA.jpg');
```

resulting:

```
"á, é, í, ó, ú.jpg"
```

Comment: Doesn't works, still shows the same after the function.