# Is it safe to replace HttpUtility.UrlEncodeUnicode with HttpUtility.UrlEncode

Tags: c#, urlencode

I got a warning during building some legacy code:

> 'System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncodeUnicode(string)' is obsolete: '"This
>   method produces non-standards-compliant output and has
>   interoperability issues. The preferred alternative is
>   UrlEncode(String)."'

Is it safe to replace `HttpUtility.UrlEncodeUnicode(string)` with `HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string)`? Do both methods produce **identical** results for any string?

If not, what is the preferred alternative?

Comment: If they are telling you that one of them produces invalid output and to use another I think it is safe to assume they don't generate **identical** output.

Comment: Indeed, safe is relative...

Comment: Maybe you need to write up some test cases

Comment: They will not produce identical output. In particular, the Unicode method produces %uxxxx output which is a non-standard extension not valid for URLs per the RFC. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912811/ (a bit old, should be a good search base) for some details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do both methods produce identical results for any string?

No, example:

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncodeUnicode("☺"); // %u263a
HttpUtility.UrlEncode("☺") // %e2%98%ba
```

> Is it safe to replace HttpUtility.UrlEncodeUnicode(string) with HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string)?

Almost safe, it depends on the decoder, most decoder can handle the result from `UrlEncode` because it's standard, if your project uses a non-standard one, then it's not safe. (BTW `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` can handle both results.)

Answer (score 1):

Based on Microsoft [Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com) (which has the source code of .NET references). The `HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string)` is an alternative of `HttpUtility.UrlEncodeUnicode(string)` as shown below :

```
[Obsolete("This method produces non-standards-compliant output and has interoperability issues. The preferred alternative is UrlEncode(String).")]
public static string UrlEncodeUnicode(string str) {..} // just removed the code in case of copy-rights.
```

So, it's preferred to use `UrlEncode(*)` over `UrlEncodeUnicode(*)`, you can check the reference source from [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/httpserverutility.cs,9fb6beaf8793f77a)