# Error when using non ASCII characters in MS Office URI Schemes

Tags: html, url, encoding, office365, uri

I want to open a file using ms-excel. I read the method at [URI Schemes Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/office-uri-schemes). I am using the following code.

```
<a href='ms-excel:ofe|u|file:C:/Users/*********/Downloads/testätür.xlsx'>link</a>
```

This works fine if my filepath contains only english characters, however it gives error when using non English characters like ö,ä,ß. The link works fine without the **'ms-excel:ofe|u|'** and downloads the file but it doesn't work with it. So I can only assume the problem is here.

```
file:C:/Users/***********/Downloads/testätür.xlsx
```

If I try to open the file link above, the following error occurs
[image]

Can someone help me understand the issue here?

Comment: Your link to the docs says literally that an [`ofe` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/office-uri-schemes#edit-document) _requires_ a URI to the document based on the **http or https scheme**.  So a URI based on the [file scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) can't work…

Comment: @JosefZ Yes I have read that but I only have a file path. Somehow it works fine without any special characters so I was guessing there is some issue of encoding

Comment: @AliTurabAbbasi Did you find the solution for this? I'm experiencing same issues.

Comment: @AliTurabAbbasi Well JosefZ from comments is right, I kinda missed the http-schema part. I'll try something like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/create-virtual-directory-folder-remote-computer where I can use virtual directory under wwwroot folder and create links from there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the file path properly before using a hyperlink in the document. See [What is the proper way to URL encode Unicode characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912811/what-is-the-proper-way-to-url-encode-unicode-characters) for more information on that.

Comment: I have tried encoding my link as well but it doesn't work. I think the MS Excel needs a decoded file path whereas when we have to pass the file path as a URI, it has to be encoded. Could you suggest a workaround?